# Rails.root is Empty in Custom Rake Task in Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Maybe I missed this in the upgrade documentation, but if I output "Rails.root" in the rails console I see my app's root path. But if I reference "Rails.root" in a custom Rake task, it's empty. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Sample:

```
namespace :admin do
    desc "Import some data"
    task :import => :environment do
        csv = Rails.root + "/test/data.csv"
        raise "#{csv} does not exit. Stopping task." if !File.exists?(csv)

        CSV.foreach(csv, :headers => :first_row) do |row|
            puts(row['id'])
        end
    end
end
```

I get an exception every time because "Rails.root" is "".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with join method

```
csv = Rails.root.join('test/data.csv')
```

csv become a `Pathname` of your file.

Comment: No... that didn't work. Is my task syntax correct? i.e. "task :import => :environment"

Comment: yes the syntax seems correct and can works. Try without first / I update my answer with it. Because bad PathName generate.

Answer (score 1):

For reference:

```
Rails.root + "test/data.csv"
```

will work as well, it's the leading slash that screws things up.

```
"#{Rails.root}/test/data.csv"
```

also works (you actually need the "leading" slash there).